# Data from geoJSON API call in Larvel 5.8

Tags: laravel, api, geojson

I am trying to retrieve data from the weather.gov API - it returns the format in geoJSON and I am not sure how to actually get the data I want from it. 
If I am using the weatherbit.io API, I have no issues as it returns JSON format in which I can pull from rather easily.
I am using GuzzleHTTP to make the API call.

I am playing around with learning APIs and I have an interest in weather so I figured I would work on an application in which I could pull information from the local weather station and output it in to readable format for users in a table.

The code I am currently using is:

```
$api_call = https://api.weather.xxx/points/LAT,LON;
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      $request = $client->get($api_call);
      if ($request->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        $weatherRequest = $request->getBody();
        $requestedWeather = json_decode($weatherRequest);
        $currentweather = $requestedWeather; ** THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP ***
}
      return $currentweather;
  });
  return view('currentweather', ["currentweather" => $currentweather]);
```

When I am returning $currentweather and var_dump it to the view, it gives me all the geoJSON data but I don't know how to correctly iterate through the data to pull the information I need.
When I pull from another API it gives a different JSON format which I can just pull like so:

```
$api_call = https://api.weatherbit.xx/v2.0/current?
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      $request = $client->get($api_call);
      if ($request->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        $weatherRequest = $request->getBody();
        $requestedWeather = json_decode($weatherRequest);
        $currentweather = $requestedWeather->data;
}
      return $currentweather;
  });
  return view('currentweather', ["currentweather" => $currentweather]);
    }
```

And when I use $currentweather in my view I can pull any data I need with the object string name. I am not sure how to pull the data when it's leading off with the @Context tag.

The data I want lies in the "properties" part of the geoJSON array and I just can't seem to figure out how to get that in the way I am currently using.

This is my geoJSON array return:

```
{ "@context": [ "https://raw.githubusercontent.xxx/geojson/geojson-ld/master/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld", { "wx": "https://api.weather.xxx/ontology#", "s": "https://schema.org/", "geo": "http://www.opengis.xxx/ont/geosparql#", "unit": "http://codes.wmo.xxx/common/unit/", "@vocab": "https://api.weather.xxx/ontology#", "geometry":
{ "@id": "s:GeoCoordinates", "@type": "geo:wktLiteral" }, "city": "s:addressLocality", "state": "s:addressRegion", "distance": { "@id": "s:Distance", "@type": "s:QuantitativeValue" }, "bearing": { "@type": "s:QuantitativeValue" }, "value": { "@id": "s:value" }, "unitCode": 
{ "@id": "s:unitCode", "@type": "@id" }, "forecastOffice": { "@type": "@id" }, "forecastGridData": { "@type": "@id" }, "publicZone": { "@type": "@id" }, "county": { "@type": "@id" } } ], "id": "https://api.weather.xxx/points/xxx,xxx", "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ xxx, xxx ] }, "properties": 
{ "@id": "https://api.weather.xxx/points/xxx,xxx", "@type": "wx:Point", "cwa": "xxx", "forecastOffice": "https://api.weather.xxx/offices/xxx", "gridX": 86, "gridY": 77, "forecast": "https://api.weather.xxx/gridpoints/xxx/xx,xx/forecast", "forecastHourly": "https://api.weather.xxx/gridpoints/xxx/xx,xx/forecast/hourly", "forecastGridData": "https://api.weather.xxx/gridpoints/xxx/xx,xx", "observationStations": "https://api.weather.xxx/gridpoints/xxx/xx,xx/stations", "relativeLocation": 
{ "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ xxx, xxx ] }, "properties": { "city": "xxx", "state": "xx", "distance": { "value": xxxx.xxxxxxxxx, "unitCode": "unit:m" }, "bearing": { "value": 150, "unitCode": "unit:degrees_true" } } }, "forecastZone": "https://api.weather.xxx/zones/forecast/xxxxxx", "county": "https://api.weather.xxx/zones/county/xxxxxx", "fireWeatherZone": "https://api.weather.xxx/zones/fire/SCZ050", "timeZone": "America/New_York", "radarStation": "xxxx" } }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you simply cast $currentweather object to an array and fetch desired data by key name like $currentweather["@context"]

Answer (score 1):

Any member of the JSON object can be accessed via the same name on the object returned by `json_decode`. Your weatherbit example `$requestedWeather->data` works because everything is in a member called `data`. So... `$requestedWeather->properties` will get you what you want from the weather.gov API.

You can also pass `true` as a second argument to `json_decode` to get back a plain PHP array instead.

```
$requestedWeather = json_decode($weatherRequest, true);
var_dump($requestedWeather['properties']);
```

This is often recommended because JSON allows member names that are not valid PHP object property names (e.g., names containing hyphens).